# How to setup step by step Google Plus One button (Android)

Tags: java, android, button, google-plus

I've searched for quite a while now about how to add a plus one button in a android app. The thing is I found out how (as there is alot of questions about it). but when I put the:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
plus:size="standard"
plus:annotation="inline" />
```

code in the layout, I get a rendering error(asking me to create a class, I did, it didn't worked, I changed the: "com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton" to "my package name.PlusOneButton" and it still did not worked). then to the java coding, I add a variable to my main_activity.java file and on the onCreate I put the:

```
        mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
```

then right on this step I get the "(PlusOneButton)" underlined red, meaning it cannot be "solved".

now, what the heck am I doing wrong?

am I suppose to create a new layout and a new java file related to this new layout?
what exactly am I suppose to do?

Any help would be greately apreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to embed a small piece of html? You could make an html page with just a +1 button on it.

Comment: Did you import the class?

Comment: Are the Google Play Services included in your project? They're required. See http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html for instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't done that. maybe that woud be the solution to it. I'll get back to you here in a while to tell if it worked!